# Can't install Ubuntu from USB stick on Macbook Air

Tags: system-installation, usb, macbook-air

Yesterday I tried to download Ubuntu with [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) steps on a MacBook Air (6,2). I got to the GRUB loader and selected to Install Ubuntu. I assumed that this would work, so I (impulsively) removed the OS X and continued with the installation. Then, after it installed, it told me to restart. Except, when I restarted and the USB stick was out, there was no boot loader, so obviously it didn't install properly.

When I insert the USB stick, I'm able to "try Ubuntu without installing", but not able to install it. Additionally, when I "try Ubuntu", WiFi doesn't work, so I have to use a USB-to-Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get your ubuntu live cd up and running with networking (wired/bluetooth/however you can). Then select the recommended proprietary broadcom driver. This should solve your networking.

Next download boot-repair ([instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) and run this from the live CD. Select 'repair recommended' and it will ask you to perform some steps in the terminal to purge/reinstall grub.

Reboot and you should be up and running. In the event that this does not solve your problem (as was my case) you will need to:

1. Boot the OSX recovery partition (or disk/usb)
2. Erase and repartition your entire disk. Create 1 partition for your ubuntu partition and another for swap.
3. Reinstall Ubuntu - Select 'something else' from the install options. Change the EFI partition to "Do not use", then install ubuntu and swap to the other partitions.

At this point you will have an unbootable system.

- Boot into the live cd again, enable networking and run boot-repair as mentioned above.

It's a pain I know but for some reason ubuntu and mac's don't always play nice.

Good luck!